# mongoose : Version error is happening with .save method on up-gradation to 5.0.9

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

**Server.js File**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var db = mongoose.connect(url, options , function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(chalk.red('Could not connect to MongoDB!'));
        console.log(chalk.red(err));
    }
});
```

**model.js  // Start**

```
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
exports.CartSchema = new Schema({
    schemaName:{type: String,default: 'MyCart',required: 'Schema Name cannot be blank'},    
    displayName : String,
    payment:{
        method:String, 
        status:String, //paid or due
    },  
    customer:{
        userId:String,
        firstName:String,
        lastName:String,
        email:String,
        phone:Number
    },
    analytics:{
        ipAddress:String,
        userAgent:String,
        referer:String,
        cookieId:String
    },
    referralServer:{
        name:''
    },

    system: {
        createdBy: {type: Schema.ObjectId},
        dateCreated:{type: Date,default: Date.now},
        dateUpdated:{type: Date, default: Date.now},
        isEnabled:{type: Boolean,default:true},
        isDeleted:{type: Boolean,default:false},
        _id:false,
        id:false
    },
});
var Cart=mongoose.model('Cart', exports.CartSchema );
```

**// End of Model.js**

**controller.js  //Start**

```
var dynamicCart= {
  "displayName": "Desktop Cart",
  "payment": {
    "method": "Cash",
    "status": "Paid"
  },
  "referralServer": {
    "name": "none"
  },
  "analytics": {
    "referer": "self",
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36"
  },
  "customer": {
    "userId": "58d5d5dssd4d55d4d5d5d45d5",
    "email": "nvprasad@gmail.com",
    "firstName": "Prasad",
    "lastName": "NV",
    "phone": 99999999999
  },
  "system": {
    "isDeleted": false,
    "isEnabled": true,
    "dateUpdated": "2017-03-07T17:54:02.294Z",
    "dateCreated": "2017-03-07T17:54:02.294Z"
  }
}

var cart= new Cart(_.extend(dynamicCart);

   cart.save(function(err) {
       if (err) {
           callback(err);
       } else {
           result=cart;
       callback(result);
      }
```

**controller.js  //End 
  When End Point (route) called the following error happening 
 **

Error :-

```
{ Error
at MongooseError (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/index.js:12:11)
at model.Model.save (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:322:25)
at _save (/app/app/controllers/orders.server.controller.js:84:9)
at /app/app/controllers/orders.server.controller.js:173:13
at /app/app/models/sequence.server.model.js:32:13
at model.Query. (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3907:16)
at /app/node_modules/kareem/index.js:297:21
at /app/node_modules/kareem/index.js:135:16
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
message: 'No matching document found for id "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"',
name: 'VersionError' }
```

Thanks,
Prasad